# it is still submitting page even though I clicked on Cancel in confirm box

Tags: jquery

Hi below I have a submit button  and a jquery function it performs when the submit button is clicked on:

```
<p><input id="submitBtn" name="submitDetails" type="submit" value="Submit Details" onClick="return myClickHandler();" /></p>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function myClickHandler()
{
     if (validation())
     {
         showConfirm();
         return true;
     }

     return false;
}
</script>
```

Now as you can see if the validation() function is met, then it will perform the showConfirm() function and this function will perform the confirmation box which is below:

```
function showConfirm()
{
    var confirmMsg=confirm("Make sure that your details are correct, once you proceed after this stage you would not be able to go back and change any details towards Questions, Options and Answers for your Assessment." + "\n" + "\n" + "Are you sure you want to Proceed?" + "\n" );

    if (confirmMsg == true)
    {
        submitform(); 
        return true;  
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

function submitform()
{
    var fieldvalue = $("#QandA").val();
    $.post("insertQuestion.php", $("#QandA").serialize(), function(data)
    {
        var QandAO = document.getElementById("QandA");
        QandAO.submit();
    });  
    alert("Your Details for this Assessment has been submitted"); 
}
```

My question is this. If the user clicks on OK in the confirmation box, then it submits the page which is fine. But if the user clicks on Cancel, then it should not submit the page. The problem is that it is submitting the page even though the Cancel button has been clicked on. Why is this?

UPDATE:

I have tried this code below but still no luck:

```
function myClickHandler()
{
     if(validation())
     {
         return showConfirm();
     }

     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if(validation()){
    showConfirm();
    return true;
}
```

You don't do anything with the return from `showConfirm();`. You just `return true` after that function is done. Try `return showConfirm();`.

---

If the user clicks Cancel in the `showConfirm()` function, then it does not execute the `submitform()` function, and the `showConfirm()` function returns false. But since you don't capture that return value, the `myClickHandler()` function returns true, which doesn't prevent the form from being submitted.

You probably just want the `myClickHandler()` function to always return false, and let the form submission be handled by your `showConfirm()` function.

---

**UPDATE:**
Here is a (IMO) better way. I'm not sure that you need to use AJAX (the `$.post` call) at all. Try this:

```
<form id="QandA" action="somepage.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return myClickHandler()">
    <!--
        ...
    -->
    <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" name="submitDetails" value="Submit Details" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myClickHandler()
    {
        if (!validation())
            return false;

        if (!confirm("Make sure that your details are correct, once you proceed after this stage you would not be able to go back and change any details towards Questions, Options and Answers for your Assessment." + "\n" + "\n" + "Are you sure you want to Proceed?" + "\n" ))
            return false;

        // if all you're trying to do is submit the form to insertQuestion.php,
        // then skip this AJAX call. I'm assuming that you need to do something
        // on the server before submitting the form. if not, skip this.
        $.ajax({
            url: "insertQuestion.php",
            data: $("#QandA").serialize(),
            async: false
        });

        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I have included an update in the question trying the `return showConfirm();` code but still no luck.

Comment: Ok so should I do this `function myClickHandler(){
     if(validation()){
           showConfirm(); return false;
     }` and then do ` function showConfirm(){

         var confirmMsg=confirm("......" );

         if (confirmMsg==true)
         {
         submitform(); 
         return true;  
     }
}
}
`

Comment: If you do that, you won't prevent the form from being submitted due to you clicking the submit button. You need the `myClickHandler` function to return false. Perhaps try changing the event to `onmousedown` or `onmouseup` or move the event to the form element and use `onsubmit`.

Comment: Can you show me what you mean by moving the event to the form elemant and use onsubmit, Im a little confused on that lol

Comment: @user1653070: I updated my answer with what I think is a better solution. It looks cleaner and more straightforward instead of keeping track of who returned what to where.

Comment: Do i still need the showConfirm() and submitform() jquery functions because in your answer I do not see them?

Comment: @user1653070: No, you don't need them anymore with my solution. Let me ask you this: are you purposely attempting to make an AJAX call to the server **AND** submit the form? Because that's what is happening in your example. If you simply want to submit the form, no AJAX call is needed. If you don't want the page to reload, then you should just do the AJAX call and don't submit the form.

Comment: I need the AJAX call because the ajax will send the data to the insertQuestion.php script and in that script it will insert the data into the database

Comment: Ok, then what does your form submission do?